# Sticky navigation with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, sticky

I'm using gumby framework.
I'm using a menu like this:

```
 <section class="page" id="portfolio" data-slide="portfolio" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">

  <header id="navigazione">
    <div class="navbar" id="nav1">
      <div class="row">
        <a class="toggle" gumby-trigger="#nav1 > .row > ul" href="#"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>
        <h1 class="four columns logo">
          <a data-slide="home" href="#">
            <img src="img/gumby_mainlogo.png" gumby-retina />
          </a>
        </h1>
        <ul class="eight columns">
          <li data-slide="portfolio"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li data-slide="about"><a href="#">Chi sono</a></li>
          <li data-slide="contact"><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</section>
```

This is a single page website. with stellar.js I can scroll with parallax effect the entire site dividen in .

now I want that this navbar is sticky when I scroll (the navbar is in the second section of the site there is an home section then portfolio and so on...)

so i try to use jquery waypoint and use the syntax

```
$(.navbar).waypoint('stycky');
```

but nothing happend...
the plugin works because if I do:

```
    $(.navbar).waypoint(function() {
alert('pippo');
});
```

it works!
I dont know what to do. I also try other plugin like smint but nothing happend...!
the other strange thing is that if I do

```
$(.navbar).fadeOut();

$(.navbar).waypoint(function() {
   $(.navbar).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

the script works but not the animation...

I hope someone will help me to understand this...because I'm getting mad...
thanks a lot in advace

Comment: Try $(".navbar"), so _with_ the quotes

Answer (score 0):

- should be 'sticky' not 'stycky'.

Also is your CSS class for Navbar having the position set to "fixed"? You should confirm that it is for Waypoint Sticky to work

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/